# How do I take user input and then sum/add to the database in django

Tags: django, database, input

I am trying to get the user input and add to the database.

Example:

A user is going to type an integer, then this is to be added to the current value in the database. It's like sending money to someone via online banking.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to use Django's ORM, you will need to define a model. In your model you will have fields that define the data items to store. After you've had Django's manage.py tool setup the database, you can create instances of your model saving them with the `save` method of your model instance.

This probably seems like a lot of hand waving, and it is. What you should do is work through the Django tutorial as it will answer your questions. The tutorial is at [the Django documentation site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/).

Comment: Hi! I forgot to mention that I have the forms up and running. I just don´t know how to acessed in the Views the database and then add to it what the user input typed. thanks

Comment: You don't access the database directly. If your view is called from a form post, you will need to use the Queryset to get the model instance you're working on. Take a look at part 3 of the tutorial.